# Salesforce community does not ask authorization

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites

I have created community and want to set Visualforce Page as default home page. When I set as Community home **Community builder page (main)** [image]

and go to the community URL, it asks me to log in [image],

but if I change it to VF page [image] - authorization does not require (I can go to the community from any device without registration and logging in). In **Login & Registration** chose Community Builder Page as login page [image] I tried to set default - the same result.

**How to do the community ask to authorize when Community Home page is VF page?**

Comment: Which template you are using? Napili or vf+tab? Make sure your community default accessibility is not set as Public.

Comment: @αΥβ  When is community default accessibility set? Template - Customer Account Portal. I tried to change it to vf+tab - the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried changing the Page Access setting to Requires Login.**

[image]